# Laravel Blade - retrieve element by id

Tags: php, json, laravel-5.6, laravel-blade

I would like to retrieve an element by the id.

**inside my blade file:**

```
{{ $auctionStatuses }}
```

**This outputs:**

```
[
    {
        "id":1,
        "name":"Awaiting customer action",
        "created_at":"2018-10-04 10:14:08",
        "updated_at":"2018-10-04 10:14:08"
    },
    {
        "id":2,
        "name":"Transfer in progress",
        "created_at":"2018-10-04 10:15:11",
        "updated_at":"2018-10-04 10:15:11"
    },
    {
        "id":3,
        "name":"Completed",
        "created_at":"2018-10-04 10:15:14",
        "updated_at":"2018-10-04 10:15:14"
    }
]
```

I would like to output the name when referencing by the id field

Due to some data coming from mongodb, i can't use the standard relationships

I have tried this `{{ $auctionStatuses['3'] }}`
but that doesn't exist, obviously.

i guess ideally, i would like to do something like this

`{{ $auctionStatuses[*]->id['3']->name }}`

Is there a way to do what i need, without looping through the json array?

Comment: You can create custom blade directive https://scotch.io/tutorials/all-about-writing-custom-blade-directives
And use like @auctionStatus($auctionStatuses, 3)

Answer (score 5):

With one line:-

```
$auctionStatuses->toArray()[array_search(3,array_column($auctionStatuses->toArray(),'id'))]['name']
```

### Explanation

`toArray()` Method converting a laravel collection to an array.

`array_search` Will searching for a array element and returning the index

`array_column` will returning values with specify column

Answer (score 3):

You can use :

```
$auctionStatuses->firstWhere('id',3)->name;
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/collections#method-first-where

Comment: This answer is better than my answer.